# NFS cache on Linux client but only for metadata?

Tags: linux, nfs, cache, metadata

I have several mounts shared via NFS. They contain loads of files, from text files to RAW photos.

Issuing `find` on them is rather painful as even on 1GbE link it just doesn't happen as smooth as on local FS, even kept on spinning rust.
Once i run find on given directory, subsequent reads are lightning fast. Keep in mind that i am talking about attributes as size, access rights and placement on directory tree, NOT the actual files' contents.

At first i thought that i could parse somehow `ls -lR /nfs/mountpoint`, put it into DB and run my "finds" over DB data, but i thought that there's maybye already something which can keep "snapshots" of remote/given filesystem's metadata, possibly refreshing periodically?

I'd like to emphasize on fact that files's content caching is beyond scope of my question.